# Primefaces popup dialog validation shown in parent Window?

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I have included a PF dialog Window in my current page , code is below

```
  <p:dialog id="dialog" header="Add Specification Feature" appendToBody="true" modal="true" widgetVar="featureDialog"
                            resizable="true" dynamic="true">
     <c:if test="#{equipTemplateBean.showAddFetDialog}">
            <ui:include src="EquipmentFeatureAdd.xhtml" />
    </c:if>
  </p:dialog>
```

and in same parent window i have this code to open dialog Window

```
<p:commandLink id="create" actionListener="#{equipTemplateBean.addSpecFeatures}" oncomplete="featureDialog.show();"  
 update=":contentform:tabView:message,:contentform:tabView:dialog">
</p:commandLink>
```

But both are under one `<h:form>` Now when i click on the parent Window button then it is checking validation of pop dialog as well and showing validation message .

How to ignore popup dialog Window validation in Parent Window?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `process` attribute to specify in the same way as `update` what elements have to be processed, this way you can avoid dialog processing.

Comment: Anyhow i have to open dialog on the commandLink Clicked.I have plenty of CommandLink in page but dialog should be open on click on this ButtonLink.